# Why did IE autocomplete stop working after updating an aspx page?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, webforms

I changed some text on an .aspx page to reflect a new phone number.  No other changes.  Did not update any .DLLs on the web project.  Now users complain (I've verified) that IE's autocomplete feature is no longer working.  I've turned on autocomplete, reset defaults, etc. to no avail.  No server settings for headers were changed.  Appears to affect SSL and non-SSL environments.

Comment: What happens if you undo the change? Does it work again?

Comment: If I replace it with the previous version of the file, yes.

Comment: Then something you changed caused issue. I would start by looking at the differences between the two files.  WinMerge can help with that.

Comment: And I can edit the original version of the files in place, rather than pushing a copy onto the servers, and the autocomplete remains just fine.  Weird.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what was changed.